# Bold 1 without subscript - indicator function?

Tags: notation, machine-learning

I'm trying to understand the notation I've found in a paper which doesn't seem to be defined within the text. I can't quite recreate it in MathJax but it looks something like:
$$\propto \Bbb{1}(\overset{\Delta}{\pi}(f^a_t), u^a_t)$$
In the paper the 1 is blackboard bold style. I'm not sure what the significance of the **1** is. At first I thought it was an indicator function but there's no subscript and it takes two parameters.

Here's a [pic of the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B9iI.png) with more context. It's from an RL [paper](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/foerster19a.html) if that is relevant.

How do I interpret this 1 function?

Comment: I fixed your typesetting so the $1$ is now $\Bbb{1}$. Unfortunately, I can't help with what it means without more information. Can you give us a link or a reference to the paper?

Comment: $\mathbb{1}(a,b)=1$ if $a=b$ and zero otherwise

Comment: @RobArthan Does the link to the paper not work?

Comment: @TedBlack I emailed the paper authors and that is indeed the case. Do you want to turn it into an answer?

Comment: Your link is fine and I was being dumb. Please ignore the last sentence of my comment.